# Seleccionar fila de un tableview y pasarla a otro tableview que esta dentro de un VC para guardarla

Tags: swift

Tengo dos entidades en coreada:

Entidad: Listado y Territorio

Su respectivos Tableview por cada entidad que pasan la información mediante un segué al ViewController, para añadir registros de cada entidad.

En el VC Territorios añadi en la parte media un TVC, y un Button para ir al TVC de la clase listado y al presionar una fila ese dato me lo envié al TVC que esta dentro del VC de la clase Territorios, donde también tengo añadido a mitad de pantalla el TVC que espera recibir el la fila seleccionada en el TVC de la clase Listado.

Tengo relacionado las entidades Listado -> Territorios. Y uso Coredata.

Como hago eso? he buscado un monto de veces y no logro encontrar nada en internet.

les dejo un video muy corto de lo que intento hacer en swift... en Objetive C ya lo he logrado.

Video: https://1drv.ms/v/s!AqJ93qWzlrtLgax6skIm4cbd0UVVCg

///////De este view controller quiero llevarme la fila seleccionada //////

import UIKit

import CoreData

import MessageUI

class ToDoTasksTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

```
 var totalTasks: Int = 0
```

fileprivate var imageItemArray = imageItem

```
var fetchResultsController : NSFetchedResultsController<Listado>!

var lista : [Listado] = []

fileprivate var  lista1 = [Listado]()

@IBOutlet weak var segment: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet weak var total: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!


func totales() {
    totalTasks = fetchData(entityName: "Listado", predicate: nil, sortDescriptor: nil).count
    total?.text = "\(totalTasks)"

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     attemptFetch1()

}

@IBAction func enviar(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    var index = 0
    var body = ""


     let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Listado")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = true


        var todos = ""

    let result = (try! context.fetch(request))

        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {

            if let terr = data.value(forKey: "mapa") {

                todos += "Territorio: \(terr)"  + "\n"// + "\n"
            }
            if let name = data.value(forKey: "nombre") {

            todos += "Nombre: \(name)"  + "\n"// + "\n"
            }
            if let direccion = data.value(forKey: "direccion") {

                todos += "Calle: \(direccion)"  + "\n"// + "\n"
            }
            if let entreCalles = data.value(forKey: "entreCalles") {

                todos += "Entre calles: \(entreCalles)"  + "\n"
            }
            if let colonia = data.value(forKey: "colonia") {

                todos += "Colonia: \(colonia)"  + "\n"
            }
            if let ciudad = data.value(forKey: "ciudad") {

                todos += "Ciudad: \(ciudad)"  + "\n"
            }
            if let idioma = data.value(forKey: "idioma") {

                todos += "Idioma: \(idioma)"  + "\n"
            }
            if let estatus = data.value(forKey: "estatus") {

                todos += "Estatus: \(estatus)"  + "\n"
            }
            if let coordenada = data.value(forKey: "coordenada") {

                todos += "Coordenada GPS: \(coordenada)"  + "\n"
            }
            if let notas = data.value(forKey: "notas") {

                todos += "Observaciones: \(notas)"  + "\n" + "\n"
            }





            print(todos)
        }


    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [todos + "\n", self.lista.last?.imagen! as Any], applicationActivities: nil)


    self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error!) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}


//MARK: - search bar related
fileprivate func setUpSearchBar() {
    let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 65))

    searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
    searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Nombre","Colonia","Direccion"]
    searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex = 0

    searchBar.delegate = self

    self.tableview.tableHeaderView = searchBar
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    guard !searchText.isEmpty else {

        return
    }

    imageItemArray = CoreDataManager.fetchObj(selectedScopeIdx: searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex, targetText:searchText)
    tableview.reloadData()
    print(searchText)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableview.reloadData()
    self.totales()

    filtrocolonia()

}


// MARK: - Table view data source

 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return (fetchedResultsController1.sections?.count)!

}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
{

}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15,y: 4,width: 400,height: 25))
    label.text = self.tableView(tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: section)
    view.addSubview(label)
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left


    return view
}

func filtrocolonia() {
    let fetchRequest1 = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Listado")
    let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nombre", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest1.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1]
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

        let sectionInfo = (fetchedResultsController1.sections?[section])! as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo

        let totalCompletePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ciudad = %@", sectionInfo.name)
        totalTasks = fetchData(entityName: "Listado", predicate: totalCompletePredicate, sortDescriptor: nil).count

        return "Ciudad: \(sectionInfo.name)" + "  (\(totalTasks))"


} else if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

         let sectionInfo = (fetchedResultsController1.sections?[section])! as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo

        let totalCompletePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "colonia = %@", sectionInfo.name)
        totalTasks = fetchData(entityName: "Listado", predicate: totalCompletePredicate, sortDescriptor: nil).count

        return "Colonia: \(sectionInfo.name)" + "  (\(totalTasks))"

    }

    else if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        let sectionInfo = (fetchedResultsController1.sections?[section])! as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo

        let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nombre", ascending: true)
        let totalCompletePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "mapa = %@", sectionInfo.name)
        totalTasks = fetchData(entityName: "Listado", predicate: totalCompletePredicate, sortDescriptor: sortDescriptor1).count



        return "Territorio: \(sectionInfo.name)" + "  (\(totalTasks))"
    }
    return nil
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let sectionInfo = (fetchedResultsController1.sections?[section])! as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo

        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ListadoTVCell
    configureCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)



    return cell
}

func configureCell(_ cell: ListadoTVCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let record = self.fetchedResultsController1.object(at: indexPath) as? Listado {
        cell.configureCell(record)


    }
}


// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

// Edit mode
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    tableview.setEditing(editing, animated: true)
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let compartir = UITableViewRowAction(style:.normal, title: "Compartir"){
        (action, indexPath) in

        var listaa : Listado!

         let cell = self.tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ListadoTVCell



        self.configureCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
        let n = cell.nombre.text
        let r = cell.referencia.text
        let d = cell.direccion.text
        let c = cell.colonia.text
        let e = cell.calles.text
        let u = cell.coordenada.text
        let no = cell.notas.text
        let f = cell.imagenView.image
        let estatus = cell.estatus.text
        let idioma = cell.idioma.text
        let ciudad = cell.ciudad.text


        let nombre = "Nombre: " + n!
        let reference = "Territorio: " + r!
        let dir = "Direccion: " + d!
        let col = "Colonia: " + c!
        let call = "Entre calles: " + e!
        let ubicacion = "Ubicacion GPS: " + u!
        let estatus1 = "Estatus: " + estatus!
        let idioma1 = "Idioma: " + idioma!
        let ciudad1 = "Ciudad: " + ciudad!
        let espacio = " "
        let espacio1 = " "



        let not = "Notas: " + no!


        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [ reference,espacio, nombre,dir, col, call,ubicacion,estatus1, idioma1, ciudad1, espacio1, not, f, self.lista.last?.imagen! as Any], applicationActivities: nil)


        self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

           let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Eliminar") {
        (action,indexPath) in

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "¡Atención!", message: "¿Seguro que quieres eliminarlo?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Aceptar", style: .destructive, handler:
            { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                let objectToDelete = self.fetchedResultsController1.object(at: indexPath) as! NSManagedObject

                context.delete(objectToDelete)
                self.totales()

                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch {
                    print("Error in deleting record from fetched results controller")
                }


        }))

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: .cancel, handler:
            { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in}))


        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error in deleting record from fetched results controller")
        }

    }


    return [deleteAction, compartir]

}

func alerta (){

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "¡Atencion!", message: "¿Seguro que quieres eliminarlo?", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .destructive, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(ok)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "editTaskSegue" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! AddEditViewController
        let indexPath = tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow
        destination.itemToEdit = fetchedResultsController1.object(at: indexPath!) as? Listado
    }
    if segue.identifier == "getDatos" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! ViewController
        let indexPath = tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow
        destination.lista = [fetchedResultsController1.object(at: indexPath!) as? Listado] as! [Listado]
    }

}

@IBAction func segmento(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
```

//        attemptFetch()
//        tableView.reloadData()

```
    attemptFetch1()
    tableview.reloadData()
    totales()
}



func attemptFetch1() {

    if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        setFetchedResults()
        do {
            try self._fetchedResultsController1?.performFetch()
            totales()
        } catch {
            let error = error as NSError
            print("\(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

    } else if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1{
         setFetchedResults1()
        do {
            try self._fetchedResultsController1?.performFetch()
            totales()
        } catch {
            let error = error as NSError
            print("\(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

    } else if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2{
        setFetchedResults2()
        do {
            try self._fetchedResultsController1?.performFetch()
            totales()
        } catch {
            let error = error as NSError
            print("\(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }


    }
}


func attemptFetch() {
    setFetchedResults()


    do {
        try self._fetchedResultsController1?.performFetch()
        totales()
    } catch {
        let error = error as NSError
        print("\(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

//
    func setFetchedResults() {
        let section: String? = self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? "ciudad" : nil

```
    print(section)

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Listado")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "ciudad", ascending: true)
    let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nombre", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor, sortDescriptor1]
```

//        let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "ciudad", ascending: true)
//        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1]

```
    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: section, cacheName: nil)



    controller.delegate = self


    self._fetchedResultsController1 = controller
    totales()

}

func setFetchedResults1() {

    let sectiones: String? = self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 ? "colonia" : nil

    let fetchRequest1 = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Listado")

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "colonia", ascending: true)
    let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nombre", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest1.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor, sortDescriptor1]




    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest1, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: sectiones, cacheName: nil)


    controller.delegate = self


    self._fetchedResultsController1 = controller

}

func setFetchedResults2() {

    let sectiones: String? = self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 ? "mapa" : nil

    let fetchRequest1 = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Listado")

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "mapa", ascending: true)
    let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nombre", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest1.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor, sortDescriptor2]





    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest1, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: sectiones, cacheName: nil)


    controller.delegate = self


    self._fetchedResultsController1 = controller

}


// Mark: - NSFetchedResultsController Implementation

var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>? = nil

var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> {

    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }



    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Listado")
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
    fetchRequest.resultType = .managedObjectResultType

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nombre", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nombre", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1]

    _fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: "ciudad", cacheName: nil)
    _fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self

    do {
        try _fetchedResultsController?.performFetch()
    } catch {
        print("Issue in fetching records with the help of NSFetchedResultsController")
    }


    return _fetchedResultsController!

}

func FRC () {
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Listado> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Listado")
    let sortDesc = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nombre", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDesc]

    if let container = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer{
        let context = container.viewContext
        self.fetchResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        self.fetchResultsController.delegate = self

        do{
            try fetchResultsController.performFetch()
            self.lista = fetchResultsController.fetchedObjects!
        }
        catch{
            print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

// Mark: - NSFetchedResultsController Implementation II

var _fetchedResultsController1: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>? = nil

var fetchedResultsController1: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> {

    if _fetchedResultsController1 != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController1!
    }

    let fetchRequest1 = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Listado")
    fetchRequest1.fetchBatchSize = 20
    fetchRequest1.resultType = .managedObjectResultType

    let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nombre", ascending: true)

    let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nombre", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest1.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor2,sortDescriptor1]

    _fetchedResultsController1 = NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>(fetchRequest: fetchRequest1, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: "ciudad", cacheName: nil)
    _fetchedResultsController1?.delegate = self

    do {
        try _fetchedResultsController1?.performFetch()
    } catch {
        print("Issue in fetching records with the help of NSFetchedResultsController")
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController1!
}
```

//    let section: String? = self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 ? "Listado.ciudad" : nil
//
//    print(section)
    // Mark: - FRC - Delegate Methods

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableview.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    self.tableview.endUpdates()
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

    let sectionIndexSet = IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex)

    switch type {

    case .insert:
        self.tableview.insertSections(sectionIndexSet, with: .fade)

    case .delete:
        self.tableview.deleteSections(sectionIndexSet, with: .left)

    case .update:
         self.tableview.reloadData()



    default:
        return


    }

}


func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {


    switch type {
    case .insert:

        tableview.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)

    case .delete:

        tableview.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .left)

    case .update:

        configureCell(tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as! ListadoTVCell, indexPath: indexPath!)

    case .move:

        tableview.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .left)
        tableview.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)


          self.lista = controller.fetchedObjects as! [Listado]

    default:
        return
    }
```

}

Comment: Comparte el código que estas utilizando, así sera más fácil ayudar.

Comment: según tengo entendido lo que vas a estar pasando son datos de un ViewController a otro... usa protocolos para pasar los datos... y con las estructuras de core data puedes ir pasando los o el dato que necesitas...